# Read two columns alone from an excel in Azure Data Factory

Tags: excel, azure, azure-data-factory

I have my data in excel file and I am able to read the whole sheet.
But I want to read only first column and third column. I have headers in the excel. So I need to read values from A2 and from C2.

I tried reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-excel . But unable to find a way. Any ways to read these two columns alone. Can any help me what values I have to specify in range. Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Source file with 4 column

[image: 1]

Select the column that you want from and Click om Insert Pivot table and grab the range

[image: 2]

Then open the Source dataset and paste that range and preview the data.

[image: 3]

Configure the sink and publish your pipeline.
Hope, You got your answer.

Comment: It was not working for me Amit.Can you please try with A and C instead of A and B.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be a workaround.

screenshot of dataflow:

[image]

1.create two source in dataflow,range of first source:`A1:A5`,another:`C1:C5`(row num should be same)

2.create two SurrogateKey,give the key column,and start value should be same.

3.create join,setting like below:
[image]

4.create select,delete the column you don't need(sk),then you can do some transform or something else.

data preview:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Steve. I have used the mapping accordingly as it was easier than the provided solution. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @Madhanlal can you please post your solution to the question. I am also struck with something similar.